# Celebration: How to golf a marriage with a prefix free code

Tags: code-golf

We all know a conspicuous member of our community got hitched recently. As most of us are not in [Malta](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Valletta), and weren't able to fly there, I thought of a celebration question. Sort of.

The challenge is [golfing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_golf) a function (Mma only) that finds a [prefix free](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prefix_code) encoding for the letters of two sentences.

The trick is that both sentences (given as parameters) must share **the same encoding**, with one of them written backwards.

The number of available symbols for the encoding is also a parameter for the function (always less than 10), and the function should attempt to find the shortest encoding for that number of symbols. There is no a-priori guarantee that a solution exists for every parameter set.

As an example, related to our celebration:

```
we wish you the best
```

and

```
sz is the handsomest groom
```

Inspiration was taken from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3110691/353410) (which does not require a prefix free code), but is a good explanation of what is required.

Happy wedding and golfing!

Shortest code wins!

**PS:** A bounty of 100, a wedding garter and the party leftovers to the winner

**EDIT**
Clarifications. To be updated as comments and answers arise

1. No caps. Only lowercase.
2. No need to encode whitespaces, special chars or punctuation (skip them and consider only lowercase letters)
3. Your solution *should* be able to show up results before they
   are back from the honeymoon.

Comment: To [close](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/136/5) or not to close... hmmm.

Comment: @R.M Close it if you please, but don' delete tags :)

Comment: So... the shortest marriage wins? ;)

Comment: @R.M Shhhh no jokes in wakes

Comment: I'd love to do something for this, but I don't understand the question (not your fault - too advanced for me), but I can use the rest of this comment to wish  the man good luck and this advice: marriage is like Mathematica, the more you put in, the more you get out... :)

Comment: @cormullion You forgot to set the undocumented `$Patience = Infinity` before executing. Your kernel will now crash and there is no undo.

Comment: @cormullion Please feel free to ask whatever you don't understand. We are all here to learn. Ping me from chat anytime and I'll try to be more clear. No need to answer, but understanding a problem is always interesting.

Comment: Congratulations, you finally could set the bounty ;)

Comment: @Rojo By using IE instead of FF ... grrrr

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's my obligatory silly answer:

```
f[s_, t_, e_] := With[{r = #[[1]] -> #[[2]] & /@ e},
  StringReplace[s, r] != StringReverse[StringReplace[t, r]]]
p[{s_, t_}] := StringMatchQ[s, t ~~ ___] || StringMatchQ[t, s ~~ ___]
p[e_] := Or @@ p /@ Subsets[#[[2]] & /@ e, {2}]
m[s_, t_, k_] := Module[{h = Union @@ Characters /@ {s, t}, e, b = True},
  While[b, e = h /. c_String :> {c, 
   StringJoin[ToString /@ RandomInteger[k - 1, RandomInteger[{1, 10^6}]]]};
   b = p[e] || f[s, t, e]]; e]
```

Example usage:

```
m["We wish you the best", "Sz is the handsomest groom", 3]
```

It will return a list representing the encoding, such as:

```
{{"W", "012"}, {"e", "2111"}, ...}
```

Description: Creates a random encoding `e` of all the characters while it is prefixed `p[e]` or doesn't encode the strings to be the reverse of each other `f[s, t, e]`.

It'll probably work, but I wouldn't try to run it.

I'm not particularly good at golf, but if you take my handicap into consideration, I'm sure I stand a good chance.  ;-)

Comment: Silly or not, you got the bounty. Congrats!

Comment: I couldn't work out how to do it properly, let alone golf it.  :-/